# Run time error when executing doubleClick() with protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

Getting this error:

> "WebDriverError: Unable to convert: Error 404: Not found"

when executing with protractor:

```
browser.actions().doubleClick(elem).perform();
```

or

```
browser.actions().click(elem).click(elem).perform();
```

Not sure what this means and how to fix it.

Comment: What browser, browser version and what protractor version are you using?

Comment: Did you test the page behavior, with manual execution? Because it might be as simple as an invalid url (http: 404 - page not found). If it's not that, please add to your question the example, how you defined `elem` (html-code + protractor-locator)

Comment: I am using IE11, protractor 5.1.2, typescript 2.2.1. When double clicking manually, a details section is displayed with some extra information, so no error.

Comment: The code looks like browser.actions().doubleClick(element(by.xpath(`//div[text()='Text1']`))).perform();

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
var elem = element(by.xpath(//div[text()=‌​'Text1']));

elem.click().click();
```